# automate directory creation in windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, automation, directory

I have been tasked with restructuring the directory of files relating to employees. As it is now, each employee has their own folder and all the files are grouped into 3 subfolders, divided by year. I'd like to sort the files in each of the folders into 4 other subfolders that are organized by subject matter. Is there any way to automate the creation of folders and transferring of files into these folders?

If this is not a sufficient information about my issue, please say so and I will attempt to provide a more accurate explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell or any number of scripting languages/tools (Perl, Python).  The trick may be knowing which target folder each of the files should go into.  If you can determine that from the name of the file or the file type it will be trivial, but if there is some other criterion it may be harder.